# How to actively request for scans

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

How to actively request for scans?

The only way provided by the `WifiManager` API, as I understand it, is the `startScan()` method, which just starts a receiver to listen for the Wi-Fi service scans. The problem is the delay between scans, it takes too much time! If I do not move too much, no scans are received, and if I do, it takes too much time to notice.

Is there a way to dynamically request a scan?

This is the code I use:

```
    // ...
    wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifi.startScan();
}

// ...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    List<ScanResult> results = this.wifi.getScanResults();
    // ...
```

Edit:

If it isn't clear...

The `onReceive` method receives scans sometimes, but it takes too long. I want to trigger a scan, not just wait for it comes. It can be done in a thread, repeatedly making it scan, as @Barns suggested.

Comment: Maybe I do not quite understand what you are asking. But, If you want to trigger a scan you could use a background thread on a loop at certain intervals to trigger the the scan.

Comment: @Barns, sorry it wasn't clear. I do want to trigger the scan, not just wait for the service to notify one. What do I use to trigger? Continuously (at intervals) calling `startScan()` in that thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred coding solution would incorporate a `Handler` with a `postDelayed` instead of `Thread.sleep`. It is important to remove any Callbacks!

Try something like this:

```
private boolean continueLoop = true;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

private void startAutoDownloadManager() {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "AutoDownloadManager - Started");
        // here the delay (in this example it is effectively the interval) is 1 second
        myHandler.postDelayed(mAutoDownloadManager, 1000);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Runnable mAutoDownloadManager = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(continueLoop){
            // preform the scan
            this.wifi.startScan();

            //re-trigger the call to start the scan
            startAutoDownloadManager();
        {
    }
};

// Make certain that you remove the callback when you leave the activity -- maybe in onPause()
private void stopAutoDownloadManager(){
    try{
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(mAutoDownloadManager);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Barn suggested, the `startScan()` can be used to trigger the scan.

My mistake was thinking that this method only starts the scan's result receiving, leaving everything to the wifi service. But no, it does trigger the scan.

So... **It's a silly question**, but I will leave it here, maybe it helps somebody else.

The code:

```
    // ...
    new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while (true) try
    {
        this.wifi.startScan();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Location", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I meant. Below, I made some slight changes to your code--(although your code will work nicely). My suggestion simply uses a `Handler` with the `postDelayed` instead of `Thread.sleep`.